# Reducing or increasing a <div> in height for every pixel scrolled down or up with Jquery with maximum of the original height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to figure out how to reduce a `<div>` in height by 1 pixel for every 1 pixel scrolled down and then increase in height for every 1 pixel scrolled up. With a maximum increase/decrease equal to the original height.

Here is an example of the `<div>` before I started scrolling, which is 40px:

```
<div class="toplayer" style="height:40px> content </div>
```

Then I scroll down 30px, it would now be this

```
<div class="toplayer" style="height:10px> content </div>
```

But if I scroll back up 5px, it would now be this:

```
<div class="toplayer" style="height:15px> content </div>
```

However this is probably the hardest part, if I scrolled down any amount of pixels that is greater than the original part height of 40px, it should be this:

```
<div class="toplayer" style="height:0px> content </div>
```

Also if I scroll back up, should never increase beyond the original 40px

Comment: you didn't make any effort to write code, we are not here to code for you...a simple search with keywords in google: "jquery scrollbar" will  give you enough intel on how to deal with your problem.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης I suppose with your reputation that is almost equal to mine you have been elected to speak for this community. `FYI - I have tried several things and I am not going to post 20 different failed methods that don't work.` Why don't you stop acting like a hot shot on this site to make up for the fact you can't answer the question to begin with and get back to learning some basic html.

Comment: and how do you know the reputation mirrors our experience? Because I am new to stackoverflow doesn't mean i am new to javascript....I know enought about scrollbars, I've made some libraries too, check for events about scrollbar position change, or else start a timer and track down scrollbar height. Keep the scroll height in one var and then find the difference between the 2, check the result and act accordingly, save the new position to the var again.

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης I looked at your answers and questions before I wrote it. I know you know more than I do on programming, but you ticked me off. How hard would it have been for you to say what you just wrote rather attacking my question?

Comment: work dude work, you'll solve it, i gave you enough information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle this with the `scroll()` event function:

```
var div = $('.toplayer'),
    divHeight = div.height(),
    scroll;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    div.height(divHeight - scroll)
});
```

Here's the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/JHxeS/1/).

A **negative** value for *height* would be invalid and the browser will render/set the min height to just 0px. So you don't need to have a condition to check for this.